# Playbook input type date change event

Tags: html, datepicker, blackberry-playbook

I'm trying to make use of the input type date on playbook, and it seems that no events are sent when a date is selected in the date picker.

Hence I cannot do any validation on that date.

Does anybody know if any event is sent when the input value is changed with the datepicker?

Edit: 
I'm developing a tablet webapp in html, the datepicker is the native one that appear in the browser.

```
<input type="date" />
```

I want to show the native datepicker when possible (iOs 5+, Playbook, ..) and a home brewed datepicker for other touch devices

Comment: Could you be more precise: are you using WebWorks, or AIR? eventually post your DatePicker code here...

Comment: For date input, you could use Picker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271966/using-qnx-ui-picker-picker-in-mobile-flex-hero-project-for-blackberry-playbook

Answer (score 0):

The events that should be fired are [`input`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#event-input-input) and [`change`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#event-input-change).  I don't have access to a Playbook or an iOS 5 device, but [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/LAEry/) works in Opera (which has also implemented native date pickers).

```
<form oninput="date_diff()">
    <label for="date1">First date:</label>
    <input id="date1" type="date" value="2011-08-24">
    <label for="date2">Second date:</label>
    <input id="date2" type="date" value="2011-08-25">
</form>
```

The `date_diff` function gets executed whenever one of the date values is changed.

Comment: It was a good idea but the input/change event aren't fired neither in the form when the value changes from the native datePicker.
I believe I'll end up changing the type to text and use my own datePicker if the device is a Playbook :(. BTW to catch the change on the iPad I need to catch the blur event, no other event seem to be fired.