# Need timePicker in Flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I need a timepicker in Flex 4.5. As yahoo astra does not work in flex 4 or above. I searched the internet and did not find any useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is one for Playbook: [Using qnx.ui.picker.Picker in mobile Flex Hero project for Blackberry Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271966/using-qnx-ui-picker-picker-in-mobile-flex-hero-project-for-blackberry-playbook)

Maybe you could do the same for other platforms?